# Upload an mp3 and use it as a buffer source

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I want to upload a file to my page and then have it played using the web audio api
Using this method, selected file returns data about the file like the name size etc. but doesn't play when put into the source.

HTML

```
 <input type="file" id="input" multiple>
```

JS

```
const selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];

const response = await fetch(selectedFile)
const soundBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
const sampleBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(soundBuffer)

const sampleSource = audioContext.createBufferSource()

sampleSource.buffer = sampleBuffer
sampleSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
sampleSource.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to fetch a file from input, in this case
`document.getElementById('input').files[0]` is enough

```
const selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
const soundBuffer = await selectedFile.arrayBuffer()
const sampleBuffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(soundBuffer)

const sampleSource = audioContext.createBufferSource()

sampleSource.buffer = sampleBuffer
sampleSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
sampleSource.start()
```

i hope help you